# C strtok seperator returns → ( at end

Tags: c, strtok

I have written a program that i want to input for example "11:12" to and then get "11" and "12" back. This is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main(void)
{
char s[] = "";
char seperator[] = ":";
char *ch;
while (1)
{
scanf("%s", &s); //scanf("%s", &s);
if (s == -1) break;
char *result = NULL;
result = strtok(s, seperator);
while( result != NULL ) {
    printf( "result is \"%s\"\n", result );
    result = strtok( NULL, seperator );
}
fflush(stdout);

}
return 0;
}
```

but when i input "11:12", this is my output:

```
result is "11"
result is "12→ ("
```

How can i get rid of the last "→ ("?

Comment: Start by cranking up the warning level on your compiler and fixing all of the warnings.  I see at least two real problems that would cause warnings, and a third real problem that results in undefined behavior at runtime (which the compiler probably won't catch, but it might if it's smart enough).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not allocating any memory for your "s" array. Try it out like this:

```
char s[128] = "";
```

Plus, you are doing a double indirection on *scanf* with parameter *&s*, it is not necessary since "s" will be decayed to a pointer as a parameter to the function.
Try it like this:

```
  scanf("%s", s);
```

Answer (score 3):

You are defining `s` to be a string of length 0

```
char s[] = "";
```

So when you're reading into a string of length 0 with your `scanf()`, bad things will happen. Assign it some memory:

```
char s[100];
```

Also, you don't need the `&` in your `scanf()`. Just `scanf("%s", s)` will do.

And while we're at it, what is this trying to do?

```
if (s == -1) break;
```

Because that doesn't work... if you want to check if a `"-1"` was entered you need to use something like strcmp:

```
if (strcmp(s,"-1") == 0) break;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has *undefined behaviour*.

```
char s[] = "";
```

With this line, you are declaring an array of chars with length 1 which means effectively you can store only null. So when you read input, you are overflowing `s` thus invoking UB.

You can also get rid of `&s` in the scanf as array name is same as its address.

Another issue is:

```
if (s == -1) break;
```

`s` is an array and hence it's address can't be -1. This comparison doesn't make sense.